# Problem in updating database table in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to update Basic table in my database but it doesn't generate any effect in table.
I am using following statement

```
sql ="UPDATE Basic SET Current_city='"+ TextBox1.Text +"',Home_Town='"+ TextBox2.Text +"';
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Any exceptions thrown? What are the current contents of the Basic table?

Comment: First of all, that code is prone to some nasty SQL injection. Second, its impossible to help you without some more info. Are you able to do other queries against the same database and tables?

Comment: ... and are they any different to the text boxes values?

Comment: I can recommend looking into using Linq2SQL, there are some good guides on Scott Guthries blog:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx
This is part 3, I think there are about 19 in total.

Comment: try the solution and accept ans if it work for you

Answer (score 2):

Please don't concatenate SQL queries. You can read about [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) on Wikipedia.

Use parameters instead:

```
sql = "UPDATE [Basic] SET [Current_city]=@City, [Home_Town]=@Town";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar, TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Town", SqlDbType.VarChar, TextBox2.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, that keyworld Basic is reserved, use [Basic].

Answer (score 0):

**create prameterize query as blelow will resolve your issue easily..........
if you go for the code you have written will cause sql injection attack
so its better to got the parametrize query. its recommended**

```
   SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE table SET param1 = @param1", sqlConn);

   /* Parameters */
   sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
   sqlCmd.Parameters["@param1"].Value = valuedata;

   try
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlEx)
    {
        sqlErrorLabel.Text = sqlEx.ToString();
        sqlErrorLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
```